# Two menus in android

Tags: android

I want to have two menus in my android app. First one is search icon in `ActionBar` (at the top) and second is a `TextView` and pop up item at the bottom. How to achieve it? I tried `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` but it moves all the menu items to bottom. Please help!

Comment: What kind of menus do you mean? Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: I want to show search icon on action bar. Also a menu should appear at the bottom that should display a textview at left and a three vertical dot lines at right (similar to pop up menu that usually appears in the action bar, clicking on this three vetical dotlines should pop up options like 'help')

Answer (score 0):

Android has not made this possible on purpose, the action bar at the bottom (called the split action bar) only has the purpose of giving extra room for actions if it is necessary (hence the uiOptions name "splitActionBarWhenNarrow").

You could still get the desired result by manually creating a split action bar by adding a LinearLayout at the bottom of your View, and using a PopupMenu for the menu.